# Livewire 3 Pusher Listener not passing off data

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Hi there I am a bit stuck on this one. I have an event being pushed with Pusher and I can see in the debug console that the data is being passed with it, but I am unable to get it to pass to the function. Here is my listener:

```
   public function getListeners()
{
   $team_id = $this->team->id;
    return [
        "echo:maps.{$team_id},MapUpdate" => 'shareMapUpdate',
    ];
}
```

And then my function shareMapUpdate:

```
        public function shareMapUpdate($event)
    {
dd($event);
    }
```

But I keep getting Unable to resolve dependency [Parameter #0 [  $event ]] ,but I know the data is being pushed to pusher. Is there some trick to getting livewire to pass the data to the function?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with Livewire 3 and not a syntax issue. I did find the issue on their github: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/6378